# Center and top align a QVBoxLayout

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I want let the two code work simultaneously,but I don't know how to do that.

```py
self.botV.setAlignment(Qt.Aligntop)
self.botV.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
```

It just do the last one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suppose you want a central horizontal alignment and the vertical alignment in the top, then you must use the operator `|`, also be careful with the case of the variables, Qt uses camelcase:

```py
self.botV.setAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignTop)
```

Comment: The reason this works, is that generally Qt uses binary flags that can be "or'd" together in order to combine them. If `Aligntop == 1` and `AlignCenter == 2` then setting one then the other will just overwrite the previous. If you instead combine them first, you get both: `Aligntop | AlignCenter ≡ 01 | 10 == 11` (in binary)